# Checking Value of Checkbox and setting value for all other Checkboxes accordingly

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I am trying to create something like a "Mastercheckbox" that will automatically check all other checkboxes on my worksheet. So I'm trying to start the following VBA Code as soon as I click click on the "Mastercheckbox" I am using Form Tools rather than Active X to create my checkboxes in order to make sure my VBA is compatible with any machine (I read that Active X might cause some issues) and have got the following code:

```
Sub Mastercheckbox()

Dim Chk As CheckBox

With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Mastercheckbox")
    If .ControlFormat.Value = False Or .ControlFormat.Value = True Then
        If .ControlFormat.Value = False Then
            For Each chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
                If Not chk.Name = "Mastercheckbox" Then
                chk.Value = False
                End If
            Next chk
        End If

        If Not .ControlFormat.Value = True Then
            For Each chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
                If Not chk.Name = "Mastercheckbox" Then
                chk.Value = True
                End If
            Next chk
        End If
     Else: MsgBox ("couldn't check value of mastercheckbox")
     End If
End With
End Sub
```

Everything in the For Loops works, but checking the value of the Mastercheckbox just isn't working for some reason and it jumps straight to the Else case. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

being not an `ActiveX` control you must check its value against `xlOn`(corresponding to 1) and `xlOff` `(corresponding to -4146)

you may also refactor a little your code as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Mastercheckbox()        
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Mastercheckbox")
        If .ControlFormat.Value = xlNone Then
            MsgBox ("couldn't check value of mastercheckbox")
        Else
            HandleCheckBoxes .ControlFormat.Value
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub HandleCheckBoxes(val As Long)
    Dim Chk As CheckBox

    For Each Chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If Not Chk.name = "Mastercheckbox" Then Chk.Value = val
    Next Chk
End Sub
```

Comment: You are welcome. See my edit to shorten the code a little

Answer (score 1):

Since you have decided to use `User_Form` checkbox, you need to define your variables as `Shape`. And in order to check their value, you need to check if they are `xlOn` or `xlOff`.

In order to see that you read the value of "Mastercheckbox" once it's pressed, you can use the piece of code below:

```
Dim MasterCB As Shape

Set MasterCB = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Mastercheckbox") '<-- set the MasterCB  variable

If MasterCB.ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
    MsgBox "Is checked"
ElseIf MasterCB.ControlFormat.Value = xlOff Then
    MsgBox "Not checked"
End If
```

**Code for your post**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Mastercheckbox()

Dim Chk As Shape
Dim MasterCB As Shape

' set the MasterCB  variable
Set MasterCB = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Mastercheckbox")

' loop through all shapes in ActiveSheet
For Each Chk In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Chk.Type = msoFormControl Then '<-- check your shape type is User_Form type
        If Chk.FormControlType = xlCheckBox Then '<-- check if the shape is a checkbox
            If Chk.Name <> "Mastercheckbox" Then 
                Chk.ControlFormat.Value = MasterCB.ControlFormat.Value '<-- modify all checkboxes to the value of "Mastercheckbox"
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next Chk

End Sub
```